# How to set file limit for input type file with multiple attribute?

Tags: javascript

How to set file limit for input type file with multiple attribute without after submit.when you select files it allows only ten files.If any ways to do like this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<input type="file" class="files" multiple/>

$('.files').change(function(){
    if(this.files.length>10)
        alert('to many files')
});
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/s1kq0Lch/)**

Let me know is this what you exactly required

Comment: thnks, Ramkee but I actually wants to restrict to select more than 10 files

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('my-form').onsubmit = function() {
    var fileInput = document.getElementById('my-files');
    if(fileInput.files.length > 10)
        return false;
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/TheDeadOne/bkgw6au2/